# Save pandas (string/object) column as VARCHAR in Oracle DB instead of CLOB (default behaviour)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to transfer a dataframe to oracle database, but the transfer is taking too long, because the datatype of the variable is showing as **clob** in oracle. However i believe if i convert the datatype from **clob** to string of **9 digits** with **padded 0's** , it will not take that much time. data is

```
product
000012320
000234234
```

is there a way to change the datatype of this variable to string of 9 digits. so that oracle does not think of it as CLOB object. i have tried the following.

```
df['product']=df['product'].astype(str)
```

or is there something else that might slow the transfer from python to oracle ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a demo:

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host_or_scan_address:1521:ORACLE_SID')
#engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host_or_scan_address:1521/ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME')

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
           c_str  c_int   c_float
0        aaaaaaa      4  0.046531
1            bbb      6  0.987804
2  ccccccccccccc      7  0.931600

In [33]: df.to_sql('test', engine, index_label='id', if_exists='replace')
```

In Oracle DB:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                Null?    Type
 ------------------- -------- -------------
 ID                           NUMBER(19)
 C_STR                        CLOB
 C_INT                        NUMBER(38)
 C_FLOAT                      FLOAT(126)
```

now let's specify an SQLAlchemy dtype: 'VARCHAR(max_length_of_C_STR_column)':

```
In [41]: df.c_str.str.len().max()
Out[41]: 13

In [42]: df.to_sql('test', engine, index_label='id', if_exists='replace',
   ....:           dtype={'c_str': types.VARCHAR(df.c_str.str.len().max())})
```

In Oracle DB:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name            Null?    Type
 --------------- -------- -------------------
 ID                       NUMBER(19)
 C_STR                    VARCHAR2(13 CHAR)
 C_INT                    NUMBER(38)
 C_FLOAT                  FLOAT(126)
```

PS for padding your string with 0's please check [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504563/5741205)

Comment: This is what i looking for. awesome stuff. and i was right, that CLOB was the issue. it was taking a lot of time in the transfer. but your solution has significantly reduced transfer time.

Comment: @Mukul, I've changed the code a little bit, so now it dynamically calculates the maximum length of the `C_STR` column and on the Oracle side it creates a column with `VARCHAR2(13 CHAR)` data type

Answer (score 0):

use `str.zfill`

```
df['product'].astype(str).str.zfill(9)

0    000012320
1    000234234
Name: product, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but  it is still showing as CLOB object, or is it the case for any string object that gets transferred to oracle ? will the datatype be always be CLOB , should it not be varchar in oracle?

Comment: @Mukul I don't know anything about oracle or CLOB objects.  You asked > "is there a way to change the datatype of this variable to string of 9 digits".  I can answer that.  Sorry it didn't work out.