# How to make df.to_sql() create varchar2 object

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a `DataFrame` which consists of a column of strings. If I do `df.to_sql()` to save it as a table into an Oracle database, the column is of CLOB type and I need to convert it. I wonder if I can specify the type (say `varchar2`) when I create the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify SQLAlchemy Type explicitly:

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host_or_scan_address:1521/ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME')

df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace',
          dtype={'str_column': types.VARCHAR(df.str_column.str.len().max())})
```

`df.str_column.str.len().max()` - will calculate the maximum string length

NOTE: `types.VARCHAR` will be mapped to `VARCHAR2` for Oracle (see [working example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514888/5741205))

Answer (score 1):

You have to options, the first is to create the table manually and then use the `if_exists` parameter to tell pandas to append to the table rather than to drop and recreate

Option two is to use the `dtype` pass a dictionary of column names so that the table can be created appropriately. These are SQL Alchemy types so you should

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import VARCHAR2
```

and pass that in the dictionary as

```
{'mycolumn': VARCHAR2(256) }
```

or suitable length.

Ref: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html